# JavaFx: caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot be cast to class

Tags: javafx

main:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
{
    FXMLLoader rootLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    rootLoader.load();
    FXMLDocumentController fXMLDocumentController = rootLoader.getController();

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLOrders.fxml"));
    loader.load();
    FXMLOrdersController fXMLOrdersController = loader.getController();

    fXMLDocumentController.setSubSceneNode(fXMLOrdersController.getVBoxRoot());

    Scene scene = new Scene(rootLoader.getRoot());

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

controller

```
@Controller
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    Button btnOverview, btnOrders, btnCustomers, btnMenus, btnPackages, btnSettings, btnSignOut;
    @FXML
    ImageView ivDisplayImage;
    @FXML
    Label lblDisplayImageTitle;
    @FXML
    StackPane spSubScene;

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnOnActionOverview(ActionEvent event)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Loading Overview FXML");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLOverView.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            FXMLOverViewController fXMLOverViewController = loader.getController();
            spSubScene.getChildren().set(0, fXMLOverViewController.getVBoxRoot());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnOnActionOrders(ActionEvent event)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Loading Orders FXML");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLOrders.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            FXMLOrdersController fXMLOrdersController = loader.getController();
            spSubScene.getChildren().set(0, fXMLOrdersController.getVBoxRoot());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnOnActionCustomers(ActionEvent event)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Loading Customers FXML");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLCustomers.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            FXMLCustomersController fXMLCustomersController = loader.getController();
            spSubScene.getChildren().set(0, fXMLCustomersController.getVBoxRoot());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnOnActionMenus(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Load Menus FXML");
        System.out.println("You have to implement this!");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnOnActionPackages(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Load Packages FXML");
        System.out.println("You have to implement this!");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnOnActionSettings(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Load Settings FXML");
        System.out.println("You have to implement this!");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnOnActionSignOut(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("just Sign Out FXML");
        System.out.println("You might want to use an Alert that ask if they are sure they want to sign out.");
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {

        // TODO
    }

    public void setSubSceneNode(Parent parent)
    {
        spSubScene.getChildren().add(parent);
    }
}
```

error:

> Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   restaurantordersduplicatefx.FXMLDocumentController cannot be cast to
>   class restaurante.FXMLDocumentController
>   (restaurantordersduplicatefx.FXMLDocumentController and
>   restaurante.FXMLDocumentController are in unnamed module of loader
>   'app')    at
>   restaurante.RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX.start(RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX.java:40)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
>     ... 1 more

can anybody help me? I have this error and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: This looks like the project I created. https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX. This project was created using` Java 8`. I am guessing you are using Java 11 or 12. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: `restaurantordersduplicatefx.FXMLDocumentController` and `restaurante.FXMLDocumentController` are two different classes. check the package names carefully.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Sedrick yes is this project java 12 and javafx and spring, i try use for study the stages .

Comment: I think @mrmcwolf found your problem.

Comment: @Sedrick yes u is keeptoo? good channel bro , thanks mr mcwolf.